# How domain name service starts?

Tags: web, dns

Can anybody tell me how the domain name service (searching for the IP of a website) starts?

Or in other words, what happens after I type a web address (say www.google.com) in a browser, press enter and before the DNS server start searching. Is there any communications between my browser and some port of my computer; between the ports of my computer to that of my ISP DNS server?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You hit enter, the browser services your request by making a network DNS query, queries the DNS server, the DNS server resolves the 'web address' to an IP address. From here on out, the IP address handshake begins to set up the connection between you and the web server.

There are more specifics in each one of these steps that I have not touched on, but here is some info:

1.

> DNS primarily uses User Datagram Protocol (UDP) on port number 53 to
>   serve requests. DNS queries consist of a single UDP request from the
>   client followed by a single UDP reply from the server. The
>   Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) is used when the response data
>   size exceeds 512 bytes, or for tasks such as zone transfers. Some
>   resolver implementations use TCP for all queries.

2.

> There are two types of DNS messages: queries and replies, and they
>   both have the same format. Each message consists of a header and four
>   sections: question, answer, authority, and additional. The header
>   field "flags" controls the content of these four sections but the
>   structure of all DNS messages are the same.

3.

> The Domain Name System specifies a set of various types of resource
>   records (RRs), which are the basic information elements of the domain
>   name system. Each record has a type (name and number), an expiration
>   time (time to live), a class, and type-specific data. Resource records
>   of the same type are described as a resource record set (RRset).

Comment: So, which port on my computer (the client) is used to send the DNS query to the DNS server? Is it also 53 (as the DNS server) or any other port?